# Superimposing high resolution but partial coverage images on a smaller resolution images for use in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, png

For the same area, I have 2 sets of images, the first is high resolution but it doesn't cover fully the area and the images have somehow uneven borders just like this picture.

[image]

The second one has smaller resolution, but practically covers my entire area of interest.

I want to superimpose the high resolution images on the smaller resolution image set, but without having these big black images appearing on the map, so I will have to make the black transparent.
I can batch replace with ImageMagick the black color with transparent, but the problem is cannot make PNG converted from the original JP2 to work on GeoServer, while somehow I had managed to make the GeoServer work for the ECW format converted from the original JP2 files. The original .jp2 files were accompanied by .j2w georeference files.
I have to mention that in order to convert the original JP2 files to PNG I use GDAL with a command line `gdal_translate -of PNG "C:\Users\userDesktop\file.jp2" "C:\Users\userDesktop\file.png"`

I have tried using the png.aux.xml and tried not to, tried to copy from the .prj files from another set that worked and tried not to, all to no avail...

Edit:
Finally with the help of gdalinfo to make sure during each step the georeference was not lost and after various tries, the correct steps are the following
1) Jp2 to png conversion using GDAL
2) png to png_transparent conversion using ImageMagick
3) png_transparent to ecw conversion using GDAL again.

Comment: PNG is not a very good format to use - GeoTiff is going to work much better

Comment: I didn't know that GeoTiff can be transparent! The thing is that again I am having difficulty to insert GeoTiff into Geoserver too using the ImageMosaic option...

Comment: can you clarify exactly what your issue is - converting jp2 to geotiff? adding images to image mosaic? or setting the background to transparent?

Comment: Ian I can convert .jp2 to .tif (using GEOTIFF) in GDAL as well as .png files that GDAL produces extra a tiny .png.aux.xml file that is like <PAMDataset>
  <GeoTransform> 3.8800000000000000e+005, 2.0000000000000001e-001, 0.0000000000000000e+000, 4.4958000000000000e+006, 0.0000000000000000e+000,-2.0000000000000001e-001</GeoTransform>
  <Metadata domain="IMAGE_STRUCTURE">
    <MDI key="INTERLEAVE">PIXEL</MDI>
  </Metadata>
</PAMDataset>

Comment: I also do not have any problems setting the backround to transparent. There must be something with georeferencing these kind of files as I had no issues when using the .ecw format

Comment: you need to [edit] your question to add these clarifications

Comment: Well finally it worked! The key tip that someone expert is to use the gdalinfo command so that I could see whether each step of my images had georeference. After lots of tries for various images formats and using gdalinfo to make sure that my last produced image had kept its georeference the steps that worked are described in my edited question